# Obtener Date de un DataObject (SDO) sin perder las horas (JAVA)

Tags: java, date

Estoy intentando obtener un date de un DataObject que me llega de entrada e introducirlo en una base de datos Oracle. El problema viene siendo que el Date que obtengo no parece tener información de la hora introducida.

Estoy utilizando el método setDate() de [DataObject](http://download.eclipse.org/modeling/emf/emf/javadoc/ecore.sdo/2.4.2/commonj/sdo/DataObject.html) con el siguiente valor: **2019-05-22T13:30:00Z**.

Por algún motivo, al utilizar el getDate() lo que me esta devolviendo es el día introducido con la hora a 0 (**2019-05-22 00:00:00**).

No estoy seguro de si debe al formato de entrada o a algo relacionado con la propia clase Date de java.utils.

Una solución fácil seria pasarlo como String y convertirlo en Date utilizando formatos pero querría ahorrarme este paso intermedio.

Agradezco cualquier ayuda que podáis darme.

Answer (score 0):

El problema resulto ser el uso del método setDate() de PreparedStatement para la introducción de la fecha en la base de datos. Usando setTimestamp() la fecha se introdujo con la hora completa.